# Need help on how to formally show that a set is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the set $H$ of all points in $\Bbb R^2$ of the form $(3s, 2+5s)$ is not a vector space, by showing that it is not closed under scalar multiplication.

To my understanding we must grab an element $\mathbf u$ from $H$ and make sure that for all scalars $c$, $c\mathbf u$ is still within the set.

If we let $s=1$ , we get the element $\langle 3 , 7 \rangle = \mathbf u$

Immediately we see it is not true that for all scalars $c$, $c \mathbf u$ still lies within the set, as $(-1) \mathbf u$ is not an element of the set.

We have shown that $H$ is not a vector space since it is not closed under multiplication.

However, I know that there is a more "formal" way to describe what i just said, i have seen many on this website use short sentences with symbols to do this. What would be a formal way of writing my chain of reason?

Comment: For a set to be a vector space it must have the additive identity - the zero element.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $(3,7)\in H$, so, if $H$ is a vector space, $0(3,7)=(0,0)\in H$. But if $(0,0)=(3s,2+5s)$ for some $s$, we have $0=3s=2+5s$. Now find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $(-3,-7)\in H$, then there is a $s\in\Bbb R$ such that $(-3,-7)=(3s,2+5s)$. But $-3=3s\iff s=-1$ and $-7=2+5s\iff s=-\frac95$.